# Faster byte math for subtraction with min of 0

Tags: java

I am doing the following for every fourth byte of two large ByteBuffers. (Subtracting the alpha of the second from the first; alpha cannot go below 0; RGBA data.)

```
static void subtractAlphaSecondFromFirst (ByteBuffer first, ByteBuffer second, int pixelCount) {
    for (int i = 3; i < pixelCount * 4; i = i + 4) {
        byte a = first.get(i);
        byte b = second.get(i);
        first.put(i, (byte)Math.max(0, a - b));
    }
}
```

Before I jump into JNI, I'd like to see if I can get some speed improvement on the `(byte)Math.max(0, a - b)` expression. Is there some set of bitwise operations that might accomplish the same thing? I would think almost certainly there is a faster way to do this than promoting two bytes to integers, running `max()` on them, and casting back to a byte, but am struggling to come up with one.

And later if I port it to C, I imagine I would still keep the same equation.

Comment: Could you do `first.put( i, ( a > b ) ? a - b : 0 )` to get rid of the max function and the integer shuffling?

Comment: I'm not sure your math is correct, as `byte` is a signed type.  What result would you expect from a value of `a` being `0xFF`/`255` and `b` being `0`?  I would expect that this should give a result of `0xFF`/`255` for alpha, but your code would result in `0`, as the math would work out to `Math.max(0, -1 - 0) == 0`.

Comment: Before doing anything else, you should pick up a profiler and measure if the time spent in your loop really is the extremely simple math, max() and the cast. I doubt that. From experience I would guess it's the ByteBuffer get/put (and all the index checking in there) that takes time. But don't take my word for it. Measure. :-)

Comment: @haraldK, I think you're probably right, but I don't think I can improve on that without JNI.

Comment: @Tenfour04 If your `ByteBuffer`s are array backed, you should get a speed increase by accessing the array directly, rather than through the buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could just make a quick comparison and a substraction using the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

```
static void subtractAlphaSecondFromFirst (ByteBuffer first, ByteBuffer second, int pixelCount) {
    for (int i = 3; i < pixelCount * 4; i = i + 4) {
        byte a = first.get(i);
        first.put(i, (b > a ? 0 : a-b));
    }
}
```

In this case "(b > a ? 0 : a-b)" means "if b is greater than a, then evaluate to 0, otherwise evaluate to (a - b)"

Comment: The main reason I didn't write an answer is because I couldn't benchmark it. If you could add some benchmarks would be a decent answer. This might not actually be faster.

Comment: i didn't see your comment until after i submitted my answer. Now here comes the funny part:  Looking at the source, the implementation of Math.max() is indeed "return (a >= b) ? a : b;", so both approaches are basically the same solution, saving only the typecasting part.

Comment: That's ok :), Typecasting and function calls may be expensive, it might be the right answer but it needs to be bench marked. My main concern is that for `is x faster than y` questions, numbers are the key to a good answer.

Comment: So, having that using the ternary operator or Math.max is basically the same thing, i would settle on that is impractical to look for a "faster" solution, as most probably the compiler will optimize this code to run pretty fast. I don´t believe that porting the code to C would improve the situation as the java JIT compiler would most likely get to similar performances.

Comment: I benchmarked it with random data, and the speed comparison from trial to trial is up to plus or minus 10% of the original, but averages about the same. So perhaps this way can potentially benefit from branch prediction if the data is more structured.

Comment: With blocky data, this method is consistently faster, averaging about 15% faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a branch-free version of the saturated subtract.  This would potentially reduce the number of branch mispredictions in the inner loop.  Something like this:

```
static void subtractAlphaSecondFromFirst(ByteBuffer first, ByteBuffer second, int pixelCount) {
    for (int i = 3; i < pixelCount * 4; i = i + 4) {
        int a = first.get(i) & 0xFF;
        int b = second.get(i) & 0xFF;
        int v = a - b;
        // Propagate sign bit into all bits and invert
        // Mask will be 0 if v is negative, -1 otherwise
        int mask = (v >> (Integer.SIZE - 1)) ^ -1;
        first.put(i, (byte)(v & mask));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I have no real way of knowing if this will improve things for you or make them worse.  I've also included a fix for what I think is a signed/unsigned problem as noted in the comments.

Comment: Benchmarked roughly 8% faster with completely random source data. I suppose the gains might be less if the source data were more blocky. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I think I was groggy when I posted the question last night because I overlooked a key fact in my use case: **The value of each byte is always 0 or FF!**

So the bit manipulation version is simple:

```
first.put(i, (byte)((a^b)&a));
```

I benchmarked it, and it is roughly 25% faster than my original version when using random source data.